# VS code doesn't select interpreter from .venv

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

VS code doesn't use my virtual env when running code (CTRL + ALT + N) and I'm not sure why. Running python files in the terminal (from within vs code) works fine after I activate the venv (`source .venv/bin/active`).

I think VS Code can see the .venv directory because it gave a pop up and generated a *settings.json* file and because the linter inside VS Code uses the .venv.

I can fix the problem for individual files by using a hacky `shebang` that I don't want in all my scripts.

I tried setting `Python: Select Interpreter` in the command palette, but it just jumps back to the default (python 2.7) environment. I'm not sure what the reason for this behavior might be.

##### project directory

```
.
├── .venv
│   ├── bin
│   ├── include
│   ├── lib
│   ├── lib64
│   └── pyvenv.cfg
├── .vscode
│   └── settings.json
└── main.py
```

##### pyvenv.cfg

```
home = /opt/miniconda/bin
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.9.1
```

##### settings.json

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": ".venv/bin/python",
}
```

##### main.py

```
import sys

print(sys.executable)
```

> /usr/bin/python

#### main.py (with shebang fix)

```
#!./.venv/bin/python

import sys

print(sys.executable)
```

> /path/to/project/.venv/bin/python

I'm using **VS Codium** , I'm not sure if the problem is a bug, or if I'm missing something here.

##### VSCodium version

```
Version: 1.59.0
Commit: 379476f0e13988d90fab105c5c19e7abc8b1dea8
Date: 2021-08-16T22:01:21.014Z
Electron: 13.1.7
Chrome: 91.0.4472.124
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.36-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.9.16-1-MANJARO
```

Comment: It's weird, I am not sure what caused it, could you provide more information? Such as some pictures of it. And have you tried to reinstall or downgrade the Python extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/issues/2490) issue on github correctly,`Run Code` depends on the OS file type association for .py files. `Python: Run Python File in Terminal` uses the interpreter selected in the workspace. So the problem is solved by reassigning the **ctrl +  alt + n** keystroke to `Python: Run Python File in Terminal` instead of `Run Code`.

The keystroke can be reassigned by removing the keystroke **ctrl +  alt + n** under **File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts**, and then adding a shortcut for the `Python: Run Python File in Terminal` command. Read the [manual](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#:%7E:text=All%20keyboard%20shortcuts%20in%20VS,This%20will%20open%20your%20keybindings.) for more info on updating keybindings.